# Linux not resolving linux hostnames but does resolve windows hostnames

Tags: windows-7, linux, dns, dhcp, ping

I have a network of computers, mainly Windows machines on a windows domain.

I have 2 Linux machines, which are connected to the network and get their IP's via DHCP from the Windows 2003 server.

My windows machine (**Win7-00**), can ping all machines by their hostnames, including the Linux machines (**N40L** and **Lin001**).

My two Linux machines can ping my Windows machines by hostname (**Win7-00**) but cannot ping the other Linux machines by hostname. i.e. **N40L** cannot ping **Lin001** and **Lin001** cannot ping **N40L**. They CAN ping eachothers the IP's. And I have an nfs export working via IP at the moment (which I wish to use via hostname)

Is this the Linux PC's not sending hostnames to the DHCP or is there something I need to change on them to allow pinging of Linux hostnames?

I don't want to manually add the hostnames to `/etc/hosts` as they're dynamic IP's and one of the machines is a laptop which sometimes won't be on the domain network.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you running a DNS server on your network? Are all the hosts configured to use it?

Comment: Yes, the Windows 2003 server has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I think I've fixed it.

I have Avahi installed, and read that I needed port 5353 udp open. I opened them on iptables and now I can ping **hostname.local**

i.e.

On Lin001 I can `ping n40l.local`
and on N40L I can `ping lin001.local`

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what distro you're using but this is how i have it set up (on centOS)

on your localhost line in `/etc/hosts` add the `"hostname.domain"` e.g fred.jane.com

`127.0.0.1 hostname.domain hostname localhost.localdomain localhost`

then in  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth#` (# is the number of the interface useing DHCP)

`DHCP_HOSTNAME=hostname`

that works for me... also make sure you have setup windows DHCP to be able to auto update DNS

Comment: I am on Ubuntu based systems. I have `send host-name gethostname();` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Comment: instead of using gethostname(); have you tried just having `send host-name "hostname"`

Comment: and shouldn't you be editing   /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf? and not /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

Comment: I only have /etc/dhcp/